# Can individual words be highligted and coloured in a DataCombo Box?

Tags: vb6

I have a datacombo box bound to a table in my database containing customer names
e.g

- Barack Obama
- Obama James John
- Joe Happier
- John Whites
- Beauty John James
- Jane Shayne

Now, i want the datacombo box to filter words similar to words i type in the datacombo box, which means if i type "John" for example, i want the datacombo box to filter all names that contains John, not only the ones that starts with John. So if i type "John", the datacombo box would only show the following :

- Obama James **John**
- **John** Whites
- Beauty **John** James

Secondly, i want the words i type to be highlighted in all occurences of that word. In this case, i want "John" to be highlighted and possibly coloured in all names that contains "John"

Is it possible with datacombo box ? If not possible, what other alternative can i use in VB6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I don't believe this is possible with the standard VB6 Combo Box. There's probably 3rd party Combo Box alternatives that you could use but it's hard to find 3rd party VB6 components that you can still buy.

A suggestion, using standard VB6 controls, would be to use a text box and a list box. The text box would be above the list box. The list box would contain your items and the text box would be used for filtering.

Create a method for filling your list box with the values. The method should have take a string parameter as a filter.

As the user types in the text box you can call the method and pass in the text they typed as the filter for your method.

Depending on how many items are in your list you may want to have a Apply Filter button so the user initiates the filter. If it's done as they type then your list box will probably do a lot of flickering as it's continually repopulated.

Comment: My apologies....i meant to say "datacombo" not "combo"....what i bound to my database table showing the customers name is a datacombo and not a combo box....My apologies

Comment: I still don't think it's possible with a DataCombo. The old VB6 components are pretty crap. Even the DataList is kind of crappy in that if you bind to a Recordset which has a Filter set, it ignores the filter and just shows all records.

Comment: You could do something like I mentioned above using a DataList but instead of binding your DataList to your recordset you can create a new recordset that holds the values you want to display and bind your DataList to that recordset. As the user types in the text box you can apply a filter to your actual recordset, loop through it's records (which will be filtered) and populate the recordset used for your DataList. Kind of clunky but would work. I

Comment: It would work, but the second half of the requirement, with highlighting the matched text of each record, still wouldn't. I'd imagine this could be done with a RichTextBox fairly easily.

Comment: Ah, so if you had "John Smith" and "Beth Jones" in your list and the user type "th" then you want the "th" in each name to be highlighted in some way? That definitely wouldn't be possible in a DataCombo or a DataList. You could populate a RichTexBox with a list of the items and that would allow different formats for the text, but you then lose the ability to have the user pick items.

Comment: With built-in functionality, that's correct. But something could be written to get the item clicked via the cursor index i.e. https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/358513-select-modify-data-within-richtextbox-mouse-click . But VB.NET was created a long time ago so I don't know why anyone would still go through this trouble.